# arrays of generic class in JAVA

Tags: java, generics

i am new with generics and i have a problem with creating an arrays of generic class.

if i have one and i want to create in a seperate main at the same java project  generic array wich answer two diffrent types-string and integer.

can i put two difreent types the same array?

and is it ok to call the main like this:

```
public static <T> void main(String[] args) {

    String name;
    int grade;
    int choice;
    int count = 0;
    String number;

    System.out.println("press 1 if you like to save id as integer ,or press 2 to for a string ");
    choice = s.nextInt();

    Student<T>[] array = new Student[NUM_OF_STUDENTS];

    if (choice == 1) {

        System.out.println("please enter student name :");
        s.nextLine();
        name = s.nextLine();

        while (!name.isEmpty() && count != NUM_OF_STUDENTS) {
            System.out.println("please enter student #" + (count + 1) + " grade :");
            grade = s.nextInt();
            array[count] = new Student(count + 1, name, grade);
            count++;
            ...
```

....

Comment: Why is student even generic? What do the generics allow you to do?

Comment: the class student is generic beacause it aloows to add the student id as integer or string as the user request.

Comment: In that case, a much simpler solution would be to save it as a string, but have a ```getAsInt``` method that parses the id. (But you're probably doing this to learn so...)

Comment: i cant use a generic array wich include both??there isnt such thing in generic?

Comment: Okay, so this is terrible by design, if you must make his ID to just be String... you can convert any integer to string, but it looks like in your case only integer is good.... there is such things as just having Student with 2 different constructors, but it is really not necessary in this case

Comment: Generics and arrays are much harder to make work together than just sticking with generics: `List<Student<T>> list = new ArrayList<>();`.

Comment: And if you can choose whether the ID is an `Integer` or a `String` in this method, the array elements would have to be of type `Student<?>`, since they could be either type. The type variable is already "set" by the time you choose the kind of ID.

Comment: I could not understand exact question of yours .Arrays need information of its content type during runtime, unlike Collection classes. So generics can be used in list, which will eventually lost during run time ( type erasure) . So unlike list, you can not have that type of information in array. Also look at invariant vs covariant  for additional details

Comment: There is no point for `main` to be generic when `T` is not used in the parameter or return types

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating a class wrapper that was just a generic free extension of the generic version:

```
  private class Bag<T> { // My generic class here
     // .. some implementation for Bag of T
  }

  public class IntegerBag extends Bag<Integer> { // Generic free!
  }

  public class UseArrayOfBagByCheating {
     private IntegerBag[] = new IntegerBag[10];
     // ... etc
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

[According to Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays), no you cannot have generics arrays.

P.S.:  you forgot to initialize *s*, which I am assuming is a *java.util.Scanner*,

```
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Also don't do:

```
System.out.println("please enter student name :");
s.nextLine();
name=s.nextLine()
```

Just do:

```
System.out.println("please enter student name :");
name=s.nextLine()
```

Otherwise *s.nextLine()* skips one line.

Comment: That floating `s.nextLine()` is necessary.

Comment: `public static <T> void main(String[] args) { ... }` compiles and runs fine for me. It isn't useful, but it is legal. Don't forget that the JVM only sees the erasure of the method, which is identical to `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: Also, `String... args` is legal too.

Comment: Considering the comments above, your answer basically boils down to _According to Oracle, no you cannot have generics arrays._ That's not very helpful. Please extract the parts of the document that explain that generic arrays are not possible and why.

Comment: How is the `s.nextLine();` necessary? Running this (well, a shortened test version) I had to type something for the first _nextLine_, press enter and then type something again for the second _nextLine_ which was then stores as name. Using only `name = s.nextLine();` worked fine.

Comment: Because the `nextInt` leaves a dangling new line character, assuming they pressed enter after providing input. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods?rq=1).